# How to open a specific url in the current Safari tab with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I've set up a button for the Touch Bar in Safari which should open a specific url in the current tab. It'd be very helpful if someone could help me here! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using AppleScript to talk to Safari, tabs are contained by windows. So to get the current Safari tab, you first need the current Safari window. The current window is `window 1`. Window 1 is the current window in many, if not most, applications: windows are indexed by their order of visibility, with window 1 being the topmost window.

The current tab in Safari is `current tab`. Tabs are indexed according to their order in the tab bar, which means that tab 1 is not necessarily the current tab; it is the left-most tab (assuming that tabs are ordered left to right in your tab bar; I do not know, but this may vary based on localization).

To open a URL in a tab in Safari, you use `set url to` and then the URL. So, for example, this script will open stack overflow in the current tab of the current window:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        tell current tab
            set URL to "https://stackoverflow.com"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time answering my question and explaining how it works along the way! It works great :)